# define routing for complex data transport objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

Being able to define the routing like so:

```
Route("Calculator/AddTwoNumbers/a/{a}/b/{a}")]
public IHttpActionResult AddTwoNumbers(double a, double b)
```

is great to invoke an endpoint like this:

```
http://localhost:64466/Calculator/AddTwoNumbers/a/1/b/2
```

I am curious what to do in scenarios where the payload/data transport object (DTO) becomes more complex (i.e. hierarchical). Take above's excample, this may be a corresponding DTO:

```
public class PayLoad
{
    public double a { get; set; }
    public double b { get; set; }
}
```

something like this:

```
Route("Calculator/AddTwoNumbers/a/{a}/b/{a}")]
public IHttpActionResult AddTwoNumbers(PayLoad payLoad)
```

does not work as there does not seem to be 'model binding' (?) as in asp.net mvc.

What am I suppose to do if the DTOs are more complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate your `payLoad` parameter definition with the `[FromUri]` attribute:

```
public IHttpActionResult AddTwoNumbers([FromUri] PayLoad payLoad)
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 ways to solve get data with WepApi:
1- Using **[FromUri]**: 
To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the [FromUri] attribute to the parameter. The following example defines a GeoPoint type, along with a controller method that gets the GeoPoint from the URI.

```
public class GeoPoint
{
public double Latitude { get; set; } 
public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
}
```

The client can put the Latitude and Longitude values in the query string and Web API will use them to construct a GeoPoint. For example:

```
http://localhost/api/values/?Latitude=47.678558&Longitude=-122.130989
```

2- Using **[FromBody]**: 
To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

This code is explained here: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)